# Error (10686): SystemVerilog error at file.sv(8): InstAddress has an aggregate value

Tags: system-verilog

I am trying to compile the following SystemVerilog, and I get the following error "Error (10686): SystemVerilog error at InstRom.sv(8): InstAddress has an aggregate value."

```
module InstRom#(parameter A = 16, parameter W = 9)
(
input InstAddress[A-1:0],
output logic InstOut[W-1:0]
);
    logic[W-1:0] instr_rom[2**(A)];
    always_comb InstOut = instr_rom[InstAddress];

    initial begin
        $readmemb("cordic.txt", instr_rom);
    end
endmodule
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since `instr_rom` has a width of `W-1:0`, the destination variable `InstOut` must be a packed array. Declare it as `output logic[W-1:0] InstOut`.

Comment: I have updated it as you suggested and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Please post the updated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*InstAddress* is an unpacked array of **bit**, not a **bit** vector (i.e. a packed array). The same applies to *InstOut*. Change the declaration to

```
input logic [A-1:0] InstAddress,
output logic [W-1:0] InstOut
```

and your code should work.